# Flatten a list with ignoring specific pattern of rows

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list (65,2) as follows:

```
[[1  2]
 [2  3]
 [3 4]
 [4 5]
 [5 6]]
```

Now I want to flatten this list to be (65) where even rows will be ignored. The needed output should be like this.
`[1, 2, 3 , 4 , 5 , 6]`
(1st row, 3rd row, 5th row)

Comment: List or numpy array?  You say list, but the display looks like an array (no commas).   With an array, flattening is easy - with `ravel` or `flatten`.  Selecting even rows is same for lists and arrays, `arr[::2]`

Comment: @hpaulj yes it is an arry. thank you. useful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flatten after slicing:

```
>>> ar = np.column_stack([np.arange(1, 6), np.arange(2, 7)])
>>> ar
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 4],
       [4, 5],
       [5, 6]])
>>> ar[::2].ravel()
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your example:

```py
lists = [[1, 2],
         [2, 3],
         [3, 4],
         [4, 5],
         [5, 6]]

[x for pair in lists[::2] for x in pair]
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```